# How to upload with ExpediaGroup's graphql-kotlin?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-kotlin

There's nothing related to file upload in the examples under https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/graphql-kotlin/tree/master/examples/server/spring-server/src/main/kotlin/com/expediagroup/graphql/examples/server/spring.

I'd like to upload 5 files at once and although I think it should be a mutation I'm not sure whether it should go like this:

```kotlin
class UploadMutation: Mutation {
    fun upload(files: FilePart) {
        print("$files")
    }
}
```

The context is obviously Spring Boot with Kotlin and WebFlux.

Comment: obviously you should start with https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developers they don't support Apollo-like file uploads at all.

Comment: File uploads can be built using our library and spring boot, but they are not included out of the box. You will have to configure the response parser yourself

https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/graphql-kotlin/discussions/1037

Answer (score 0):

File uploads can be built using our library and spring boot, but they are not included out of the box. You will have to configure the response parser yourself

https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/graphql-kotlin/discussions/1037